# jquery validation with $.post

Tags: jquery, validation

```
    $('#gstrate-button').click(function() {
    if ($('#gstrate').is(':empty')) {
        $('#rate-error').text("Required");
    }
   else{
        url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>settings_controller/save_new_gstrate";
    $.post(url, {rate: rate}, function(e) {
        location.reload();

    });


});
      }
```

my  else  part  is  not working!!How  to  solve? The  field  to  be validated  is  inside the pop up  and it is  text  field and id is '#gstrate'.

Comment: You should not be using the [tag:jquery-validate] tag if you're not using this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
      // do other stuff for a valid form
    form.submit();
   }
   });
```

Via jQuery docs, here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 0):

`:empty` actually checks if the element has any children elements, which an input can't have.

What you want is to just check if the value is an empty string

```
if ( $('#gstrate').val() === '' ) { ...
```